# What's the code for length in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand what `length` is all about. Say we have vector `A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and when we code up `length(A)` it spits out `8` for the # of elements.

How does the `length` command work? 
I've been thinking it's a for loop like

```
A = [could be any size];
for i = A   % takes each element of A
     i = i+1;  % add 1 for each new element thus counting the elements
end
```

Please help me understand it.

Comment: It is in fact equivalent to `max(size(X))` which can be seen by entering `open lenght` in the command window (as long as `length` is not overridden or defined as a variable).

Comment: @zheyuan-li, `length` is built-in, so there is no source code to read. A better suggestion would be to go read about representation of arrays in memory, etc.

Comment: I would guess that Matlab uses some data type that internally keeps track of its size. The length is then just part of the variable that the function returns. For sure there is no loop involved. What would be the end-condition anyhow? In Matlab this kind of information is hidden to the scripter, and I would just accept that it works.

Comment: @nirvana-msu You know that the built-in comment on `length` especially names this equivalency?

Comment: @Bernhard, this was a response to another commend _"go read source code"_, which is already removed. Regarding `max(size(X))`, yes, the comment mentions that results are equivalent, but this is just to explain what `length` does, not how it does it. The actual implementation has nothing to do with `max(size(X))`.

Comment: @nirvana-msu How do you know that the actual implementation has nothing to do with `max(size(X))`? I would not be surprised if it actually IS implemented like that.

Comment: @Bernhard, right, what I meant to say is that actual Matlab's `max` and `size` functions are more complex (dealing with various inputs / outputs) than what's needed to calculate array length. But conceptually, yes, `length` likely is just taking a maximum of the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how `length` works you need to understand the details of how Matlab stores its data structures internally in memory. Mathworks don't really disclose much detail, but here's the relevant points from [How MATLAB Allocates Memory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-allocation.html#brh72ex-9):

> **Array Headers**
>
> When you assign an array to a variable, MATLAB also
>   stores information about the array (such as class and dimensions) in a
>   separate piece of memory called a header.

So the dimensions are already stored together with the array. All that `length` needs to do is find the maximum of them.

Also worth noting that (from the same doc):

> The following topics provide information on how the MATLAB® software
>   allocates memory when working with arrays and variables. The purpose
>   is to help you use memory more efficiently when writing code. Most of
>   the time, however, you should not need to be concerned with these
>   internal operations as MATLAB handles data storage for you
>   automatically.

...

> **Note**   Any information on how the MATLAB software handles data
>   internally is subject to change in future releases.

Answer (score -3):

You should expect some behavior like accessing the size of the array at system level. Matlab of course knows how large it is since it has to ask for memory, so no need to really run through it and count the number.

Anyway, your example code does not work as desired. According to [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html), in each loop `i` is equal to a slice of array `A`. `i` is an independent variable that does not affect `A`. `i=i+1` only means adding `1` to a variable that is equal to a certain part of `A`.

If you really want to "count" the elements then

```
c = 0;
for ii = 1:length(A)
    c = c+1;
end
```

But in order to begin the loop you need length of A in the first place....